How to create a Windows Service to execute a JAR file automatically when the system is started?
I want to create a Windows Service to execute a JAR file Automatically when the system starts. I've tried creating it manually without using any 3rd party wrappers, but ended up lost. Guide me on how to achieve this..
I faced issues in updating status of the service to SCM, still didn't get it resolved. I have searched online and ChatGPT, got recommended tools such as Apache procrun and NSSM. Not sure which one is good and safe, because I want to use it on a client's machine.
This is the powershell script I have used to create a service. It initiates the service, the JAR file got executed and the console log generated fine, but not updating the status of the service and after 5-10 mins, it is being automatically stopped.
$serviceName = "E-invoiceService"
$logFilePath = "path\einvoiceServiceInfo.log"

function WriteLog {
    param (
        [string] $msg,
        [string] $logLevel = "INFO"
    )
    $logmsg = "$logLevel - $(Get-Date -Format 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') - $msg"
    if ($logFilePath) {
        Add-Content -Path $logFilePath -Value $logmsg
    } else {
        Write-Host $logmsg
    }
}

# Define service status constants
$SERVICE_STOPPED = 1
$SERVICE_START_PENDING = 2
$SERVICE_STOP_PENDING = 3
$SERVICE_RUNNING = 4
$SERVICE_CONTINUE_PENDING = 5
$SERVICE_PAUSE_PENDING = 6
$SERVICE_PAUSED = 7
$service_timeout = 30

# Function to update service status with logging
function UpdateServiceStatus {
    param (
        [int]$status,
        [int]$win32ExitCode = 0,
        [int]$waitHint = 0
    )

    Add-Type -TypeDefinition @"
    using System;
    using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

    public class ServiceControlManager {
        public const int SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS = 0x00000010;

        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct SERVICE_STATUS {
            public int dwServiceType;
            public int dwCurrentState;
            public int dwControlsAccepted;
            public int dwWin32ExitCode;
            public int dwServiceSpecificExitCode;
            public int dwCheckPoint;
            public int dwWaitHint;
        }

        [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        public static extern bool SetServiceStatus(IntPtr hServiceStatus, ref SERVICE_STATUS lpServiceStatus);
    }
"@

    $serviceStatus = New-Object ServiceControlManager+SERVICE_STATUS
    $serviceStatus.dwServiceType = [ServiceControlManager]::SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS
    $serviceStatus.dwCurrentState = $status
    $serviceStatus.dwControlsAccepted = 0
    $serviceStatus.dwWin32ExitCode = $win32ExitCode
    $serviceStatus.dwServiceSpecificExitCode = 0
    $serviceStatus.dwCheckPoint = 0
    $serviceStatus.dwWaitHint = $waitHint

    try {
        # Get handle to service status
        $statusHandle = [System.IntPtr]::Zero
        if (![ServiceControlManager]::SetServiceStatus($statusHandle, [ref]$serviceStatus)) {
            throw "Failed to set service status."
        }

        # Log information
        WriteLog -msg "Service status updated to $status." -logLevel "INFO"

        switch ($status) {
            $SERVICE_STOPPED {
                WriteLog -msg "Service is stopped." -logLevel "WARN"
            }
            $SERVICE_RUNNING {
                WriteLog -msg "Service is running." -logLevel "INFO"
            }
        }
    } catch {
        # Log error if updating service status fails
        WriteLog -msg "Failed to update service status. Error: $_.StackTrace" -logLevel "ERROR"
        WriteLog -msg "Stack Trace: $($_.Exception.StackTrace)" -logLevel "ERROR"
    }
}

try {
    # Update service status to START_PENDING
    UpdateServiceStatus -status $SERVICE_START_PENDING

    # Start the service
    WriteLog -msg "Starting service '$serviceName'..."
    Start-Process -FilePath "java" -ArgumentList "-jar", "path/e-invoice.jar" -NoNewWindow

    # Wait for the service to start
    Start-Sleep -Seconds $service_timeout
    WriteLog -msg "Service start sleep time - '$service_timeout' seconds"

    $service = Get-Service -Name $serviceName
    $stopWatch = [System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch]::StartNew()

    while ($service.Status -ne 'Running' -and $stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalSeconds -lt $service_timeout) {
        Start-Sleep -Seconds 4
        WriteLog -msg "Refreshing service status. Current Status - $($service.Status.ToString())" -logLevel "INFO"
        $service.Refresh()
    }
    WriteLog -msg "Refreshing service status. Current Status - $($service.Status.ToString())" -logLevel "INFO"
    if ($service.Status -eq 'Running') {
        # Update service status to RUNNING
        UpdateServiceStatus -status $SERVICE_RUNNING
    } else {
        throw "Service failed to start within the timeout period."
    }
} catch {
    WriteLog -msg "Failed to start service '$serviceName'. Error: $_.StackTrace" -logLevel "ERROR"
    WriteLog -msg "Stack Trace: $($_.Exception.StackTrace)" -logLevel "ERROR"
    # Update service status to STOPPED
    UpdateServiceStatus -status $SERVICE_STOPPED
}



You just need a task scheduler for execution and that has to be setup during start up. Long back, I wrote THIS. You can take help on how to build task scheduler job in PS from it.

Thank you for the comment!, but still I can't able to run the JAR as a Windows Service using procrun, Then later I had to go with NSSM, and then, with very minimal work, I've successfully created a Windows Service which runs my JAR file. It's very easy and user-friendly to use by the way. This is the NSSM guide I've followed: How To Run A JAR As A Windows Service With NSSM
But still I'd really like to get a solution for the procrun issue I've faced. Thus, any further answers are appreciated!
